# Voltage regulator circuit calculations (zener diodes, transistors)

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-regulator, zener, calculation

[image]

The circuit given in the following Figure is a voltage regulator which is used to supply a constant voltage. It has the following properties:  Vin = 20V, Rs = 1 kΩ, R1 = 200 Ω, R2 = 800 Ω, R3 = 2 KΩ, RL = 100 Ω, Vz = 5.6V, βdc = 100.

Vin = 20V
Rs = 1kΩ
R1 = 200Ω
R2 = 800Ω
R3 = 2kΩ
Rl = 200Ω
Vz = 5.6V
βdc = 100

Vf = 0.7V (?)
Vout = 5.6V (?)
Ic2 = ?
Ib2 = ?
Ic1 = ?
Iz = ?
PQ2 = ?
Pz = ?
RL = ?

I am having immense trouble with this one. So far, Vz = Vout when using a Zener diode? So 5.6v?
Vf = 0.7v? (Threshold voltage of a diode?)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to simulate the circuit, poke around and see what values affects which parameters?

Comment: I have replicated the circuit and placed current probes but I am getting 0 on all of them. I'm out of my depth.

Comment: Please share a screenshot. This problem should be entirely solvable in SPICE.

Answer (score 1):

> *Any help would be appreciated!*

Maybe you should think along these lines; ask yourself what voltage has to appear on the base of Q1 (with respect to ground) such that base current begins to flow. I mention this because, when Q1's base current starts to flow, you reach the onset of the circuit turning into a voltage regulator.

Then, once you have established this value, you can calculate what the output voltage must be. This requires recognizing that the R1 and R2 form a potential divider from the output to Q1's base.

Comment: 5.6 - 0.7? = vF?

Comment: voltage divider circuit?

Comment: No. 5.6 - 0.7 = Vout?

Comment: @NonComposMentis I don't understand any of your three comments. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.